# Presentation for Kernel of Induction map from $\oplus R(H)$ to $R(G)$

Tags: representation-theory

This is an exercise in Serre's representation theory book: Suppose that $X$ is a family of subgroups of $G$ stable under conjugation and taking subgroups

Let $N$ be the kernel of map $\mathbb{Q} \otimes Ind: \oplus_{H \in X} \mathbb{Q} \otimes R(H) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \otimes R(G)$. The claim is that $N$ is generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by elements $(f_H)_{H \in X}$ such that

1. If $H' \subset H$ then $Ind^H_{H'}(f_{H'}) = f_H$
2. If $H \in X$ and then $f_{sHs^{-1}}$ is the function $^sf_H$ on $sHs^{-1}$ defined to be $^sf_H(shs^{-1}) = f(h)$.

Now the hint says that we should tensor with $\mathbb{C}$ and look at the dual, i.e. the map $\mathbb{C} \otimes Res$ and then show that if $(f_H)_H$ is a class function satisfying the analogous properties of the above conditions, then there exists $H$ such that $Res^G_H(f) = f_H$ for each $H$. Now I believe that the above $2$ conditions are precisely the things we need to make $f$ well-defined: namely, if $g \in sHs^{-1}$, then just set $f(g):= f_H(s^{-1}gs)$.

This is well and good but I am not sure how this shows that the kernel is spanned by elements of the above form. In particular, we know that all such elements will be perpendicular to the kernel of the induction because, by Frobenius reciprocity, we have that $(Res^G_H(f), \psi) = (f, Ind(\psi)) = 0$ if $\psi$ is in the kernel of $Ind \otimes \mathbb{C}$.

Any help would be appreciated!